# Couldn't read row from CursorWindow. Error when rotating image from gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-gallery

Im accessing image from gallery or directly from camera in my app. Before sending it to server, I have to be sure that image is not rotated incorrectly. So I'm using function for it to get rotation from gallery or from image taken by camera.

Everything is working as intended without issues, but on `Xiaomi Mi A1` it is causing this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Camera image error returning from intent(actually what is in Logcat in AndroidStudio):

```
E/mm-camera: <MCT   ><ERROR> 1108: mct_pipeline_decide_hw_wakeup: Couldn't find meta stream
```

Android version is 9.0. But this is for 100% not version related. I have another Android 9.0 phone where this is working without error. How is it accessing column -1 in gallery when I picked a photo from first row and second column?

**Also for camera intent -> there is no exception thrown in console at all -> app will not stop working, only error toast show up( because `onActivityResult' intent is`null`but`resultCode`is`RESULT_OK`).**

Rotation functions for gallery and camera:

```
fun getRotationFromCamera(context: Context, imageFile: Uri): Int {
    var rotate = 0
    try {

        context.contentResolver.notifyChange(imageFile, null)
        val exif = ExifInterface(imageFile.path!!)
        val orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL
        )

        when (orientation) {
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> rotate = 270
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> rotate = 180
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> rotate = 90
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return rotate
}

fun getRotationFromGallery(context: Context, imageUri: Uri): Int {
    val columns = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION)
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(imageUri, columns, null, null, null) ?: return 0

    cursor.moveToFirst()

    val orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0])
    return cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex)
}
```

Maybe I should include how I access camera and gallery:

```
private fun openGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        a.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY_NODE_MISUSE)
    }

    private fun openCamera() {
        val tempFile = createImageFile()
        photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(a, app.packageName + ".fileprovider", tempFile)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(a.packageManager) != null) {
            a.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA_NODE_MISUSE)
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

After searching for few hours I've found a solution (only for taking photo by camera). If you open `CameraIntent` this Intent is not returning `data: Intent` even if you take photo by camera. It will actually add this photo to your empty file made by `FileProvider` (in code above it is `photoUri`). You have to read photo from this `Uri` not from `data` sent to `onActivityResult`. This is actually weird and it is only like that for `Xiaomi` phones. I've tried `Samsung` and `Razer Phone 2` (both Android 9.0) and **data is not null**.

Still there is problem why this rotation is not working for both gallery and camera Uri.